# 'Modified' normal distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, applications

I've been told many times that statistics of samples in the real world tend to approach a normal distribution given a large sample size. I've also heard this with respects to samples of sizes which are bounded, and therefore can't relate to the normal distribution , since for all $M>0$ it attains values larger than $M$ with positive probability. I was wondering therefore whether such approximation statements refer to a modified truncated normal distribution.

I had in mind the following construction:

Let $Z\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and I want to discuss a modified random variable attaining values only in the interval $[a,b]$. Then I denote:

$$ h:= \mathbb{P}(Z\notin [a,b]), $$

and define a new 'modified' random variable $Z_{[a,b]}$ with density function

$$ f_{[a,b]}(t)= \Big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}  e^{-\frac{1}{2} \big( \frac{t-\mu}{\sigma} \big)^2} +\frac{h}{b-a} \Big)\cdot \chi_{[a,b]}(t),$$

to approximate by a normal random variable under the above constraints.

Is this analysis common-place and sound, or am I overcomplicating the subject and people simply regard the 'simple' normal distribution as the approximation. Is there perhaps another simpler method used?

I ask this because I've always been confused by real life usage of probability, and why the mathematical models fit.

Comment: If $f$ is the pdf of $Z$, then density of this truncated distribution is $f(t)/P(a<Z<b)$ if $t\in[a,b]$ and $0$ otherwise. How is your $f_{[a,b]}$ a density?

Comment: @StubbornAtom If you integrate both terms, since $h=1-\int_a^b f(t)dt$, I think the total integral is $1$.